# Нет перевода для описания действий по предлагаемым правкам

Tags: дефект, локализация, очередь-проверок

Отсутствуют переводы для данных опций:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Выбирайте метку [дефект] для такого рода вопросов. Обсуждать тут особо нечего, надо утверждать.

Comment: я понял, спасибо, буду учитывать в дальнейшем

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Добавил переводы:

Approve and reopen - [Принять и снова открыть](https://ru.traducir.win/strings/16822)

This edit clearly improves the post and resolves close reason(s). - [Эта правка явно улучшает сообщение и устраняет причину(ны) закрытия.](https://ru.traducir.win/strings/16819)

Approve and leave closed - [Принять и оставить закрытым](https://ru.traducir.win/strings/16817)

This edit clearly improves the post, but doesn’t resolve close reason(s). - [Эта правка явно улучшает сообщение, но не устраняет причину(ны) закрытия.](https://ru.traducir.win/strings/16816)

Comment: Если правильно помню, «Approve» когда-то переводилось как «Принять»

Comment: можно поменять я думаю, смысл не потеряется

Comment: я вот ещё думал над "снова открыть" может лучше "переоткрыть" ?

Comment: Немного подправил и утвердил. Оставил только множественное число для "причины". Имхо, в русском не очень смотрится вариант со скобочками.